# save json to file, load it and turn it back to object

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I'm currently building an application in `python` where I have a class `Corpus`. I would like to convert this class to a `json` format and save it to a `json` file. Then load the file and finally turn back the `json` to its Class `Corpus`.

In order to do that I use the library `jsonpickle`. The problem is when I load the `json`, the type is a dictionary and `jsonpickle.decode` wants a string. I tried to convert the dictionary to a string but its not working.
I hope someone will be able to help me.
Here is my code of my class "Json" (to save and load my Corpus)"

```py
import json, jsonpickle

class Json:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.corpus = {}
        
    def saveCorpus(self,corpus):
        jsonCorpus = jsonpickle.encode(corpus,indent=4,make_refs=False)
        with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(jsonCorpus)
            
    def loadCorpus(self):
        with open('json_data.json', 'r') as f:
            self.corpus = json.load(f)
        
    def getCorpus(self):
        return self.corpus
```

error :

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: _class to a JSON file_ What do you mean by this saving class code?

Comment: Error : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: My thinking is that you need to read the data as a string then use jsonpickle.decode to convert the string.

Comment: @ConstantinHong TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
I would like to convert my class with all its attributes to json and save it to a file

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The issue was the way I was saving my json to a file.
Here is the solution:

```py
def saveCorpus(self,corpus):
    jsonCorpus = jsonpickle.encode(corpus,indent=4,make_refs=False)
    with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(jsonCorpus, outfile)
```